# Making presets using Photo editor sdk

Tags: javascript, android, swift, react-native, photoeditorsdk

I'm looking to develop a mobile app that will be able to implement presets using photoeditor sdk.
Does anybody know if I can edit one photo in Photoeditor sdk and then save these settings and use them on another photo later?

thanks ahead